# Momentum in a quantum particle in a box

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum

The momentum operator in one dimensional quantum mechanics is:
$$\hat p_x=\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{d}{dx} $$ and we can imagine creating an eigenvalue-eigenfunction system $$\hat p_x\psi = p_x\psi.$$
As a student of ODE, I see here a Sturm-Liouville problem if we let $\lambda=-i\hbar p_x$ then we can say $\psi'+\lambda\psi=0$. If we then imposed boundary conditions of a 1-D particle in a box such that $\psi(0)=\psi(L)=0$, then this generates a Sturm-Liouville problem which should have eigenfunctions of $ \psi_n(x)=\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L}) $ and eigenvalues of $\lambda_n=\frac{n^2\pi^2}{L^2}$. However, when we calculate the expectation value of $\hat p $ we get $0$. $$$$How are these solutions physically self-consistent with each other? I am confused because the solution to a PIB in an infinite well is $\sqrt\frac{2}{L}\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})$ so the eigenfunction system makes sense, but my eigenvalues don't seem to.

Comment: Related: [What's the deal with momentum in the infinite square well?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/362305/l)

Comment: #Sigh#.    Asking people to not use uncommon abbreviations or acronyms without defining them is a fruitless task.  But Il try to knock one apple off of the tree here.  *What the heck is PID?*   and please define abbreviations and acronyms on first use.  What defines "uncommon"?   I can't define it, but I know it when I see it.  :-)   Choose wisely and conservatively.

Comment: @garyp its PIB, particle in a box, pretty common in quantum chemistry, where my training is, but this is a physics group, so I understand the confusion, and I will fix. Thanks

Comment: If you see it as an eigenvalue problem for P and the „physical” boundary conditions $\psi (0) = \psi (L) = 0$, you obtain $\psi_n (x) \equiv 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\sin(px)=\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{ipx}-e^{-ipx}\right)$ is a superposition of a state with positive momentum and a state with negative momentum. The average momentum is $p-p=0$.

Your square well problem is a special case of this. Mathematically, the boundary conditions mean that you only get $\sin$ solutions, and not complex exponentials. Physically, a particle in a well can't have any net average momentum in the positive or negative direction, or else it would leave the well.

---

As Philip pointed out in another answer, there is a small subtlety in that the real wavefunction is $\theta(x)\theta(L-x)\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$ (where $\theta(x)=1$ for $x>0$ and $0$ for $x<0$), which is not purely a superposition of 2 complex exponentials. However since it is real, the wavefunction is still of the form $\psi=\phi+\phi^\star$, where $\phi$ is a superposition of *positive* momentum modes $\phi \sim \sum e^{ipx}, p>0$, and so $\psi$ has zero average momentum.

Answer (score 2):

Note also that the [expectation value of momentum for any real eigenfunction is zero](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/606347/157014).

Also, while the accepted answer by @Andrew does give you the right intuition as to why the average momentum is zero, there is a slight subtlety due to the fact that the wavefunction *isn't* $\sin(px)$ over all space, but rather $\sin(px)$ within the box and zero outside it. As a result, the possible values of momentum *aren't* just $\pm p$, but rather have some spread, as I discuss in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/609593/157014). That being said, the distribution of possible momenta is symmetric about $p=0$, and so @Andrew's argument still holds.

Comment: Good clarification!